# Schemas inside sitemap, is good way?

Tags: xml, schema, sitemap

I'm not sure what the best way to do schema and sitemapa is, check my questions.

**First question**: Does the schema work inside the sitemap? Without microdata in HTML.

`<sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/products/foo</loc>
    <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
    <product>
        ...
    </product>
</sitemap>`

Or sitemap is perfect **only** `loc`, `piority`, `changefreq` and `lastmod`?

**Second question**: Is there a problem if I put a hash address 'http://foo.com/#termos' in sitemap? Because the content is in the modal that opens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom elements in your sitemap, you can extend the sitemap protocol. See the following reference on how-to: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#extending.

However, these custom elements will be probably not leveraged by search engines, but your sitemap is still valid.

Normally, you should not not include # links, they refer to the same page. However, I don't see anything in the protocol definition about this.